# CodeBlocks is not showing source files

Tags: c, codeblocks

Just have a weird bug on codeblocks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deE1V.png)

In the picture are some projects - i want to click on the project and see his source files (main and classes) and it's just not working (right and left clicks both).
Just finding myself burning alot on time on this and i thought maybe someone here will know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Well, you are viewing the wrong tab. What happens if you click the left arrow until you come to the tab called "Projects" then click on that one?

Comment: Okay so not a bug then. I'll go ahead and post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply viewing the wrong window tab. Click on the the left arrow next to the tabs until you come to the tab called "Projects". Then click on that one. The project file structure will appear.

You can also resize the window to make it broad enough to display all window tabs.